# No Outputs section in cloudformation template

Tags: aws-cloudformation

In cloudformation template, there is an outputs sections which is used for talking to cross-stack.

Is that correct to say that this part should not exist if there is only one stack we are creating in one AWS account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The outputs section can be used for cross-stack references with `Export` and `Fn::ImportValue`. It can also be used for general output for the user. A few examples:

1. Admin URL like https://123.123.123.123/admin
2. Credentials for a newly created user
3. Identifier for any of the resources for easy access
4. An attribute of a resource like EC2 instance IP address

Comment: To answer the original question directly, the answer is no - not correct. There are good use cases for having outputs (without ```exports```) even if you only have one stack.